# MVVMCross Android Presenter to clear back stack of activities

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross, back-stack

My Android app that I am building using MvvmCross, steps through activities one by one and then "returns" to a home page.  Once the app returns to the home page I don't want the user to be able to step back through all the previous activities.

Reading through all the documentation and blog posts etc I have been able to overide a presenter and trap the request to clear the back stack of activities.

All this code works fine but I have been unable to find out how to clear the back stack of activities.  Any ideas how I can achieve this?  My code is below:

**Setup.cs**

```
public class Setup : MvxAndroidSetup<Core.App>
{
    protected override IMvxApplication CreateApp()
    {
        return new Core.App();
    }

    protected override void FillTargetFactories(IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
    {
        MvxAppCompatSetupHelper.FillTargetFactories(registry);
        base.FillTargetFactories(registry);
    }

    protected override void InitializeLastChance()
    {
       // Mvx.IoCProvider.ConstructAndRegisterSingleton<ICameraHelper, CameraHelper>();
        base.InitializeLastChance();
    }

    protected override IMvxAndroidViewPresenter CreateViewPresenter()
    {
        var presenter = new MyAppAndroidPresenter(AndroidViewAssemblies);
        Mvx.IoCProvider.RegisterSingleton<IMvxAndroidViewPresenter>(presenter);

        return presenter;
    }
}
```

**MyAppAndroidPresenter.cs**

```
public class MyAppAndroidPresenter : MvxAndroidViewPresenter
{
    public MyAppAndroidPresenter(IEnumerable<Assembly> androidViewAssemblies) : base(androidViewAssemblies)
    {
    }

    public override async Task<bool> Show(MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {
        if (request.PresentationValues != null)
        {
            if (request.PresentationValues.ContainsKey("ClearBackStack") && request.PresentationValues["ClearBackStack"] == "True")
            {
                // TODO : Clear the activity back stack
            }
        }

        return await base.Show(request);
    }
}
```

**Calling ViewModel**

```
    private async void NextPageMethod()
    {
        var presentationBundle = new MvxBundle(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "ClearBackStack", "True" } });

        await NavigationService.Navigate<HomeViewModel>(presentationBundle: presentationBundle);

    }
```

Comment: This might be useful for you: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/2848#issuecomment-395967040

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are trying to do is essentially start the "Home Page" Activity using an intent that includes the [ClearTop](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) flag. According to the Android developer documentation, adding this flag will cause the following behavior:

> For example, consider a task consisting of the activities: A, B, C, D.
>   If D calls startActivity() with an Intent that resolves to the
>   component of activity B, then C and D will be finished and B receive
>   the given Intent, resulting in the stack now being: A, B.

Looking at the MvvmCross source code for the built-in Android presenter, there are several ways you can achieve this. The simplest way is to override the [CreateIntentForRequest](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/ca57d8e979b6c3891e400135a2e1f5aa95e7fa69/MvvmCross/Platforms/Android/Presenters/MvxAndroidViewPresenter.cs#L246) method in your custom presenter. This method has the MvxViewModelRequest passed to it as a parameter. So you can modify the intent and add the `ClearTop` flag to it if the condition is right.

```
protected override Intent CreateIntentForRequest(MvxViewModelRequest request)
{
    var intent =  base.CreateIntentForRequest(request);

    if (request.PresentationValues != null) {
        if (request.PresentationValues.ContainsKey("ClearBackStack") && request.PresentationValues["ClearBackStack"] == "True") {
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);

        }
    }

    return intent;
}
```

This is just one way to achieve the clear back-stack functionality. MvvmCross is a highly extensible framework and nearly everything can be customized.